# Sum numbers and finding maximum, Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to sum the powers (r) of primlist (primes) that divides a number, and also pick out the greatest power (`k`) that makes the `primlist` divides a number. I believe I have the right concept but matlab is overlooking something in the loop. example when numbas=45, we know 3^2*5=45 so primlist = 3 and 5, for 3: k=2, r=1,3 and for 5, k=1, r=1. r is simply all the powers of a primlist that divides a numba, and k is the highest value of r. i want to sum all the r's and also get the maximum r which is k

```
n=100;    
primlist=2;    
for numba=1:n;    
   if mod(2+numba,primlist)~=0    
      primlist=[primlist;2+numba];    
   end    
end    
prims=reshape(primlist.',1,[]);    
r=1;
for numbas=2:n
    for k=1:10    
        if mod(numbas,prims.^k)==0    
            r=r+sum(k) % sum of all the powers of prims, such that prims divide numbas    
            k=max(k) % greatest power of prims, such that prims divide numbas    
        end            
    end    
end    
numbas
prims    
k    
r
```

Comment: I can run your code without getting any errors. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: no there is not error, i was just saying that i use primlist and prims interchangeably. what i am not getting is r,k,prims for each corresponding numbas. it just give the default value of r=1 and k=10.

Comment: Do you have any link explaining the algorithm you are trying to implement? If I understand correctly, you are testing whether numbers between 2 and 100 divide prime numbers to different powers. Surely no numbers between 1 and 100 will evenly divide all the primes between 2 and 100? Of course I may be completely wrong...

Comment: BTW `prims=primlist.'` and even setting `primlist=prims` doesn't give me any errors.

Comment: I went ahead and edit the discription take a look at it again. yes prims and primlist is the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you are looking for. I added an extra loop to test whether primes divide `numbas` one-by-one, rather than all at once. `r` contains the primes that divide `numbas` and `pow` contains the corresponding numbers of each. You may want to change how the results are saved, but I think this gives you what you were after.

```
n=100;    
primlist=2;    
for numba=1:n;    
   if mod(2+numba,primlist)~=0    
      primlist=[primlist;2+numba];    
   end    
end   
kMax=0;
for numbas=2:n
    r=zeros(size(primlist));
    pow=r;
    for k=1:10
        for i=1:length(primlist)
            if mod(numbas,primlist(i).^k)==0
                r(i)=primlist(i); % sum of all the powers of prims, such that prims divide numbas
                pow(i)=k;
                if k>kMax,kMax=k;end % greatest power of prims, such that prims divide numbas
            end
        end
    end
    R=r'
    POW=pow'
end
```

Comment: one more thing, you used R=r', what is the ' for?

Comment: No reason really! Just so that it displayed the results as a row vector not a column so it took up less space while I was checking that it worked! Column vectors mean more scrolling! You can get rid of those two lines without any problem.